# Signalr 404 on IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, signalr

I'm getting a 404 on my server (IIS 7) but everything works fine on my dev env (IIS Express). Any ideas what to check for? From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991697/how-does-signalr-register-its-http-handler-in-the-project) it seems like the handlers are registered automagically, so I guess there must be something else causing this.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<SignalRConnectionEndpoint>("broadcast", "broadcast/{*operation}");
```

And the 404 from `http://<server>/broadcast/negotiate`

Any ideas for what to look for?

(I've gone through the other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsignalr%5D%20404) but found nothing similar).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to WilliamBZA at http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr pointed me to the sln.

At prod server I was runnning at `<server>/<webapp>/brodcast/..` and when calling `$connection('/<webapp>/broadcasst')` I forgot the webapp at my dev was running on root.

Larsi